# ERROR: Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK or through the environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm learning how to use aws cdk, here is my code, I wanna do "cdk deploy --profile myProfile", got "Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK or through the environment",

but I already specifying my Credentials and Region by using, can anyone help me with that.

```
cdk doctor
ℹ️ CDK Version: 1.30.0 (build 4f54ff7)
ℹ️ AWS environment variables:
  - AWS_PROFILE = myProfile
  - AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG = 1
ℹ️ CDK environment variables:
  - CDK_DEPLOY_ACCOUNT = 096938481488
  - CDK_DEPLOY_REGION = us-west-2
```

```
aws configure --profile myProfile

AWS Access Key ID [****************6LNQ]:
AWS Secret Access Key [****************d9iz]:
Default region name [us-west-2]:
Default output format [None]:
```

```
import core = require('@aws-cdk/core');
import dynamodb = require('@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb')
import { AttributeType } from '@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb';
import { App, Construct, Stack } from "@aws-cdk/core";

export class HelloCdkStack extends core.Stack {
  constructor(scope: core.App, id: string, props?: core.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new dynamodb.Table(this, 'MyFirstTable', {
          tableName: 'myTable1',
          partitionKey: {
                name: 'MyPartitionkey',
                type: AttributeType.NUMBER
              }
        });
  }
}

const app = new App();
new HelloCdkStack(app, 'first-stack-us', { env: { account: '***', region: 'us-west-2' }});

app.synth();
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be the bug as in [[master] CDK CLI Authentication Issues #1656](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1656).

> if you have ~/.aws/credentials and ~/.aws/config they both can't have a default profile section.

- [cli: cdk deploy issue #3340](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3340)

> removing [profile default] from ~/.aws/config solved the issue! I had both [default] and [profile default]. Please see #1656
>   resolved the issue insert the AWS keys in the "config" file inside ~/.aws folder, and not inside "credentials" file

Comment: Hi mon, I remove default in both config and credentials, still got the error..Do I miss something?

Comment: @mcy, please leave in config but not in credentials. If default is both in config and credentials, then the issue will happen.

Comment: oh..so I need to add the default back in config?

Comment: @mcy, please put it back in config and see what happens. Please go through https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3340.